# Error when I try to generate client from wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl

I want to generate a java client from wsdl.

So I have create a new project, import wsdl into project, then right click -> web services -> Generate Client.

So this is the option that I use:

[image]

Then click on fish and I have this error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'https://edottotest.sanita.regione.rsr.rupar.puglia.it/nsisr/PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService?xsd=1', relative to 'file:/D:/Dropbox/workspace/Edotto/src/PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.wsdl'.: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:516)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Sour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WSDL imports a schema with a URL with an `https` address scheme. This error indicates that your Java installation does not "trust" the certificate presented by the server that is hosting this schema that is being imported.

You have a couple of options:

1. Import either the server's CA certificate, or the servers actual certificate into your trust store
2. Download the schema to a local location and change the import url in the WSDL

I would recommend the second option, as it is slightly more portable as long as you package the WSDL and aforementioned schema together.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try an example using the below wsdl file
     http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

to generate the client.

And make sure that you start the server. If this works fine.
Then, your problem will get solved.